# @Valid @ModelAttribute not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have this controller

```
@Controller
public class EmpleadoController {
    @Autowired
    private EmpleadoService servicio;

    @PostMapping("/empleado/new/submit")
    public String nuevoEmpleadoSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("empleadoForm") Empleado empleadoForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "formulario";
        }else {
            servicio.add(empleadoForm);
            return "redirect:/empleado/list";
        }
    }
}
```

With this model

```
package com.alexotero.spring.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class Empleado {

    @Min(0)
    private long id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String nombre;
    @Email
    private String email;
    private String telefono;

//Constructors getters setters and stuff
```

I've also added this dependency to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It doesn't matter what i introduce in the form, the controller never detects any error. Always adds the object to the List(in the service) and redirects to the list.html. I cannot find where is the problem.

Comment: Only adding the api isn't going to do anything. You also need an implementation like `hibernate-validator`. Instead of adding the `validation-api` use `spring-boot-starter-validation` which includes both the api and an implementation.

Comment: Can you also provide what you are trying to send as body to test it?

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know about the implementation. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I removed this dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and added

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I think they both conflict with each other.